# How to secure REST api in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, security, jersey, jetty

I have a Java application which uses `Jetty` library to handle websocket connections. I am using `Jersey Jax-RS` to support REST api in this application.

I have two sets of REST api's:
1. To be accessed by customers
2. To be accessed by my sys admin for diagnostics(internal)

For securing 1, I am using Oauth authentication. For 2, I cannot use Oauth or basic authentication.
But I want to secure the api's based on Role (security realm) or anything like that so that only known users can access those API's.

What are the possible ways to implement this security?

Note: The application is not a web application, so there is no web.xml, jetty.xml etc.

Comment: To the one who close voted, the question is not vague. The question is how to implement security in non-web rest application.

Comment: I am confused by your terminology. This is a web application, it just runs an embedded jetty instead of relying on a servlet container? Anyhow. You can presumably secure your internal resource the same as your external. Could you show your code? Jersey for example has a thing called: RolesAllowedDynamicFeature which enables you to additionally restrict resource methods with roles

Comment: @pandaadb External resources are authenticated using Oauth, which involves the frontend application to upload certificate and token service to provide token etc. But we cannot use any of them to secure the internal resources since it is used only within the application. The application does not have the information to support basic auth as well. I guess roles need security realm to be defined in the servlet container. How is it possible in case of embedded Jetty?

Comment: i believe this is a 2 issue question. First - how do you implement security on jersey, second how do you implement your actual security rules. I can give you a hint on how to implement this with jersey, but i don't know where your security rules (e.g. what roles does who have) come from. How do you determine what roles belong to an internal request if there is no auth passed in that request? Also - when saying within the application, are you making rest request from your jetty to the same jetty? You could use something like a shared secret for your internal application that you create yourself

Comment: How do I create shared secret myself for my internal user? I think this should be something I can use.

Comment: This would simply be a randomly generated string (uuid) that you create. You can use your os or java or anything for it. It is not a very nice solution though as it will be a hardcoded secret that both parties know (e.g. server A making an internal request to server B). Again: Do not do REST-requests from server A to server A. Only make requests if you need to talk to a different machine, otherwise design the code so you can simply use the services internally

Comment: It would be best thought for your sys admins to have some sort of authenticator (e.g. if you have internal usernames/passwords) and then you could implement an LDAP authenticator (or similar) that would check passed in user/pass combos instead of creating a shared secret and passing it around to your sys admins. A security breach with a shared secret will also be harder to quick-fix as it will require you to create a new secret and shut down/restart the service.